# Como fazer um teto mínimo e um teto máximo em um número randômico?

Tags: java, random

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java e no meu controller tenho uma função que gera os números randômicos. Exemplo:

Na minha primeira coluna quero que gere de 0 a 8, até aí OK.

Na segunda coluna quero que gere 9 a 17, aí neste caso eu não consigo fazer pois não sei determinar qual número `x` vai iniciar, pois de padrão ele conta com o começo no 0.

Ou seja, quero que gere 0 a 9, depois 9 a 17, depois 18 a 25 e assim por diante...

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
public void grupoDeSete(){
        Random random = new Random();

        /*=====ACTIVITY PLUS=======*/
        int generated1_plus = random.nextInt(9);
        int generated2_plus = random.nextInt(17 - 9) + 10;
        int generated3_plus = random.nextInt(24 - 18) + 20;

        /*Grupo de 7 números*/
        String sevenGroup = String.valueOf(generated1_plus
                + " - "
                + generated2_plus
                + " - "
                + generated3_plus);

        //Resultado
        setSecond(sevenGroup);
    }


    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(String second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
```

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Esses grupos são 0-9 e 9-17? Ou seria 0-8 e 9-17? Ou ainda 0-9 e 10-17? Além disso, você fala 18-25, mas o seu código gera 20-25. O seu código também gera 10-18. Não consigo entender qual é a lógica que você quer para essas faixas numéricas e sem isso não dá para responder a pergunta.

Comment: Então, eu tentei fazer um "esquema" para que ele gere qualquer numero que seja ate 18... entao esse 17 - 9 = 8(ele gera de 0 a 8) e depois soma + 10 dando um valor de 10 pra cima... so que queria alguma forma que determina o meu minimo e que eu possa sair dessa formula... algo que seja (iniciar entre x e y) como o exemplo

Comment: Sim, mas porquê 18? Não estou perguntando sobre a fórmula, estou perguntando quais são as faixas desejadas. Sabendo-se as faixas, achar a fórmula é fácil.

Comment: é por que queria 18 mesmo por isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
public class Sorteio {
    private static final Random RND = new Random();

    public static int sortear(int min, int max) {
        return RND.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public static int[] sortearSete() {
        return new int[] {
            sortear(0, 9),
            sortear(10, 18),
            sortear(19, 26),
            sortear(27, 33),
            sortear(34, 39),
            sortear(40, 44),
            sortear(45, 48)
        };
    }
}
```

O método `sortear(int, int)` te dá dois números dentro de uma faixa. Por exemplo, `sortear(20, 30)` dá qualquer número de 20 a 30, incluindo o próprio 20 e o próprio 30. E então o método `sortearSete()` te dá esses 7 números. É importante que você ajuste as faixas numéricas dentro desse método para as faixas que você quer.

Coloquei as seguintes faixas: uma faixa contendo 10 números de 0 a 9; uma faixa contendo 9 números de 10 a 18; uma faixa contendo 8 números de 19 a 26; uma faixa contendo 7 números de 27 a 33; uma faixa contendo 6 números de 34 a 39; uma faixa contendo 5 números de 40 a 44 e uma faixa contendo 4 números de 45 a 48.

Comment: Ahh, entendi... mas assim, quando eu vou retornar esse valor para mostrar na tela precisaria converter para string, quando eu converto ele aparece uma forma toda bagunçada... como que faria para mostrar o resultado?

Comment: @Nathan [`java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-)

Answer (score 0):

Você deve chamar `nextFloat` ou `nextDouble`, que retornam decimais entre zero e um e fazer as transformações que precisa. Mais ou menos como abaixo:

```
(int) min + (random.nextFloat() * (max - min));
```

Isso vai te retornar um int com valores entre min e max.